# Is there a way to give a numpy array variable length?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, class, object

if I wanted to get the array `[[0,0,1],[0,1,2]]` into the form `[[1],[1,2]]`, the standard numpy array system wouldn’t allow this since the shape must remain consistent. Is there any way I can convert the original array into a class or some type of object where I can have uneven length entries? If I need to use some other library or anything please let me know so I can research that as well! Thank you!

I tried researching this issue a ton but it’s really hard to find such specific information, without being overwhelmed by similar looking information.

Comment: Maybe a `numpy.ma.MaskedArray` works for you. The underlying array would still be shape (2, 3), but you could "mask" the 0 values to be ignored.

Comment: Would [Awkward Array](https://awkward-array.org/) solve your problem? To help with web-searches, these are sometimes called "ragged arrays" and sometimes called "jagged arrays."

Comment: Assuming you do create such an array, what do you then want to ***do*** with it?

Comment: " Is there any way I can convert the original array into a class or some type of object where I can have uneven length entries?" yeah, convert it to a Python list, e.g. `my_numpy_array.tolist()`

Comment: There is [awkward-array](https://awkward-array.org/doc/main/) for jagged arrays. But if your data is not too large, Python lists may work fine for your purposes: they can be faster than you think.

Answer (score 1):

@9769953 is right that if you have small datasets, builtin Python lists are best, but I don't think you'd be searching for something if Python lists would do. So here's a quick demo of Awkward Array ([GitHub](https://github.com/scikit-hep/awkward), [docs](https://awkward-array.org/)).

In line with @MatBailie's question, "If you had such a thing, what would you do with it?" these are the sorts of things you might want to do:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import awkward as ak
>>> array = ak.Array([[1.1], [2.2, 3.3]])
>>> array
<Array [[1.1], [2.2, 3.3]] type='2 * var * float64'>
```

NumPy ufuncs:

```py
>>> np.sqrt(array)
<Array [[1.05], [1.48, 1.82]] type='2 * var * float64'>
```

Reducers:

```py
>>> np.sum(array, axis=-1)
<Array [1.1, 5.5] type='2 * float64'>
```

Specialized functions that are only meaningful for ragged arrays:

```py
>>> ak.num(array, axis=1)
<Array [1, 2] type='2 * int64'>
>>> ak.cartesian((ak.Array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]), ak.Array([["A", "B"], ["C"]])), axis=1).show()
[[(1, 'A'), (1, 'B'), (2, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'A'), (3, 'B')],
 [(4, 'C'), (5, 'C')]]
```

As @user_na points out, NumPy has a `dtype=object` mode, which essentially makes a fixed-length Python list, in which each item is an arbitrary Python object. That's fine if that's what you want, but you wouldn't be able to pass such a thing into NumPy ufuncs or do any of the things above without list comprehensions or Python for loops (different syntax and slower for big data).

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this by making an object array in numpy like this

```
import numpy as np
cells = np.array([np.array([0,1,2,3]), np.array([2,3,4])], dtype=object)
```

but you will then need to address the nested array sequentially, like this:

```
>>>print(cells)
[array([0, 1, 2, 3]) array([2, 3, 4])]
>>>print(cells[0])
[0 1 2 3]
>>>print(cells[1])
[2 3 4]
>>>print(cells[1][1])
3
```

Although beeing terribly inefficient you can use it to do something like this:

```
arr = np.array([[0,0,1],[0,1,2]])

lst = []
for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
    lst.append(arr[i,np.where(arr[i,:]!=0)[0]])

arr_squeezed = np.array(lst,dtype=object)

print(arr_squeezed)
```

printing out:

```
[array([1]) array([1, 2])]
```

BUT you probably don't want to do it this way. Try if you can use `np.where(arr!=0)` or a masked array instead. If you give more details on your usecase I can be more specific on this one.